# CompletableFuture in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, completable-future

Can someone tell me how CompletableFuture is related to Reactive Programming? In Other Word can I implement some of the Reactive Principles using CompletableFuture in Java 8

Answer (score 4):

CFs are closer to  a single-shot version of reactive streams and also have the property that you can keep constructing your processing graph whether some of the stages have completed or not, while streams won't necessarily remember previously processed items if you attach another subscriber at a later point. Another thing CFs do not have to concern themselves with is backpressure.

You could also say reactive streams are instructions how to build new CF graphs over and over again as new input data arrives from a publisher/observable.

Sidenote: Java 9 will contain the [Flow](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Flow.html) interfaces that various reactive libraries can implement for interoperability.

Comment: hi, can you explain what do you mean by "CFs are closer to a single-shot version of reactive streams"? Also "Another thing CFs do not have to concern themselves with is backpressure". I am just learning reactive programming so I am not familiar with what you're  trying to convey